# How to add a loading in widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have several process when i add my widget in home, how can i add a "loading image" while it's not ready yet?

I saw that the Youtube widget had this.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question but anyway what have you tried?

Comment: Reading right now about LoaderManager and ProgressBar, to see if i can use something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made it! =)

I don't know if this is the best approach, let me show to you:

On my widget xml, i added a second Layout, that hold the Progress Bar:

```
widget_layout.xml

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/widgetProgressBar" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've put on my original layout the following code:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then, when all my process is over, i did this:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progressLayout, View.GONE);
remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.layout, View.VISIBLE);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
```

If someone have a better way, please, let us know!

Comment: Good solution, i was stucked whole day, but it worked. thanku. i was missing appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a ProgressBar?  When you start the process you can use the below code:

```
ProgressDialog mDialog;  //create a member vairable


//put this in what ever method you start your process
mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
mDialog.show();
```

And once all your process are finished you can call:

```
//call this when all processes are finished
mDialog.cancel();
```

Comment: Hmm, i don't know if is some mistake of mine, but i can't make this code works on my widget..